# Oracle SQL Formatting

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider below set of column date in oracle:

```
column_name
na
110000
440000
```

I want to achieve two things here

1. Numbers should be in the format 99999.90
2. In output, word like na/NA should be replaced by blank or num field

Comment: you want to update the table or select in that format?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? Do you have specific non-numeric values (you mentioned two) or do you want to blank out anything that isn't a number? Do your 'numeric' strings have group separators, +/- signs, currency symbols, or anything else you want to allow? Also you've only shown two integers, are those supposed to be interpreted as representing a number with a decimal part?

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when lower(col_name='na') then '' 
            else to_number(col_name,99999.90) 
       end 
from table_name;
```